# Notification mechanisms when transiting to cold state

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-function-app

When Functions app is idle for some tinme, it will be moved to cold state.

Is there a mechanism of notification when it starts to transit to code state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now no relevant notification could be used. However in this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2623#issuecomment-468053330), mathewc mentioned they are adding some APIs about getting the function status, if the status includes the `idle`, your requirement would be achieved.

Even though, you could control the [timeout duration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#timeout) or enable the `Always On`. If you want to set the timeout duration, follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout) or set like this below.

```
{
    "functionTimeout": "00:05:00"
}
```